# How to convert rails 4 app's database from sqlite3 to postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have tried multiple ways to convert my existing rails app's database from sqlite3 to postgresql. i tried converting my database.yml file's adapter to postgresql and running rake db:create and migrate but that did not work i tried adding gem 'pg' instead of sqlite3 but still does not work. I am not able to push my projects to heroku i always get an "application error" when i run my heroku web site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have *removed* sqlite3 from your Gemfile, and run bundle.

You may need to do a heroku migration.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: i did this, i removed the sqlite3 gem added the pg gem instead and did the step mentioned above but still no luck

Comment: what is the error you get when you try to push to heroku?

Comment: the website shows an application error. the logs shows no error.